# Почему у enable_if_t тип параметра по умолчанию именно void?

Tags: c++

`enable_if_t` в стандартной библиотеке определен так:

```
template<bool _Test, class _Ty = void>
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Test, _Ty>::type;
```

Но почему `_Ty` именно `void`?

---

Если бы `_Ty` был `int`, то не нужно было бы писать так:

```
template <Ty, enable_if_t<is_integral_v<Ty>, int> = 0>
void foo(Ty val);
```

Достаточно было бы написать так:

```
template <Ty, enable_if_t<is_integral_v<Ty>> = 0>
void foo(Ty val);
```

Comment: А ни так, ни так, писать не надо.

Comment: А почему должен быть int, а не char, double?

Comment: А почему так писать не надо?)

Comment: Просто необходимости нет. Тут либо `static_assert` (если нет вариантов для других аргументов), либо  `if constexpr`, либо (частичные) специализации.

Comment: @user7860670, ни то ни другое внутрь объявления не запихнуть…

Comment: @Fat-Zer Эм, я вроде и не предлагал что-то пихать в объявления.

Comment: @user7860670, просто учитывая, что у OP'а именно объявления в вопросе, столь категоричное «не надо» выглядит несколько неуместно…

Comment: @Fat-Zer То, что в в вопросе приведены объявления никак не влияет на категоричность "не надо".